# Create an ArrayList which contains a set of numbers between the user defined min and max values (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Basically, I need to create a method called:

```
public boolean doesContain(double x)
```

which works like this:

```
Returns true if and only if x lies between left and right, and the
interval is not empty (i.e. left < right).
```

And this is how the class looks like:

```
public class Interval {

    private double left;
    private double right;

    public Interval(double left, double right){
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public boolean doesContain(double x){

        ArrayList<Double> nums = new ArrayList<Double>();
        //Add code here

    }
}
```

Comment: What issue(s) are you encountering?

Comment: I want a create a list of numbers within a given range and then put in to the array...But I dont really know how to generate these numbers.

Comment: You are working with doubles and theoretically within 2 doubles there are an infinity of numbers so you cannot list all of them.

Comment: "I want a create a list of numbers within a given range and then put in to the array" - what is the purpose for it? You may not need to keep a list at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean doesContain(double x) {
    if (left >= right) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return x >= left && x <= right;
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns false if `left >= right`. It returns true only if `left < right` and x lies on one of- or between `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean doesContain(double x){
    return left < right && left <= x && x <= right;
}
```

Comment: How does this check if the interval is not empty?